# Parse saveInBackgroundWithBlock not returning error or succeeded callback

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Using both subclassing and localdatastore occasionally:

```
SPUserParseModel *user = [SPUserParseModel currentUser];
user.firstname = someString;
[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    //Nothing is returned
    if(!error && succeeded) {
     //Nothing is returned   
    }
];
```

Returns nothing, the error or succeeded bool never return. There's no debug info to look at, I've tried setting:

```
    [Parse setLogLevel:PFLogLevelDebug];
```

But still don't know how to investigate this.

I feel like there might be a Localdatastore issue, perhaps it saves locally and then corrupts somehow? But as I haven't used saveEventually and haven't explicitly changed pins, it seems odd.

Sometimes force-quitting and re-opening the app will fix the issue, but not for long.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I have also suspected the Localdatastore to be the problem, did you find a solution? Also I get the same sort of behaviour with saveeventually.